# Android ScrollView content disappearing on removing background attribute

Tags: android, scrollview, transparent

I have a ScrollView in a LinearLayout along with a header LinearLayout on top. I have given the main LinearLayout a background. If I keep the background for the ScrollView everything displays fine. But If I add a lot of content then the ScrollView background stretches. So I want to keep the ScrollView transparent.

But if I remove the background attribute or if I try android:background="@android:color/transparent" the content inside the ScrollView vanishes. All I can see is the header and the background from the outer LinearLayouts.

This is how I want my Views:

```
<Linear Layout with background image>
  <Header Linear Layout>
  </Header Linear Layout>
  <ScrollView with no background>
    <Layouts in Scroll View>
  </ScrollView>
```

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/topbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/Labels"
                android:text="@string/posts_add_postcontent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/postsAddContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/posts_add_postcontent_h"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="3000"
                android:minLines="3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: The header LinearLayout is included via another file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="@layout/bgtop_repeat"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="2dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/cornerlogo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menubuton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/menubutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/headshadow_repeat"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in included layout

Comment: Perfect! It worked! Can't believe it was such a small issue. Thanks :)